# Xdebug for RabbitMQ consumer (Docker in WSL + PhpStorm on Windows)

Tags: php, docker-compose, rabbitmq, xdebug, wsl-2

The question is a little specific and I didn't find many answers for this setup.

I have a Windows PC with WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) where is Docker running by docker-compose and code of the app. PhpStorm is located on Windows, the code is directly loaded from WSL location (for the app performance reasons).

Can someone help me setting this up?

Consumer launching by `docker-compose exec php app/console <consumer-name>`